# beamer: More elegant way to uncover list items starting on the second slide?

Tags: beamer, lists, overlays

Using LaTeX and `beamer`, I'm using the shorthanded notation `<+->` and its variants (e.g. `<+-| alert@+>`, etc.) to have list items uncovered so that I do not have to manually enter a specific number for each slide, and can insert a new list item without having to renumber everything.

However, sometimes I want to display some text that appears before the first list item is shown. The way I have done this is to create an invisible item (called `\noitem` below) and insert that as my first list item. It is admittedly a kludge ... and, furthermore, it forces the insertion of some vertical space between the text shown initially and the list. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Ideally, it should not require extra vertical space either.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\newcommand{\noitem}{\item[{\color{white} blank}] {\color{white} blank}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Some text displayed initially.
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \noitem  % invisible item shown on first slide
    \item First item, uncovered on second slide
    \item Second item, uncovered on third slide. 
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can put `\pause` before the `\begin{itemize}` line.

Comment: Of course, how silly of me not to think of that...  Thank you very much.

Comment: @André Sometimes it's the simple stuff that escapes us.  Also, I think once you learn about `<+->` you tend to internalize it as "don't ever use `\pause`", but sometimes `\pause` is just what's needed.

Comment: I have images coming after the item list which I want to be visible before the first list item becomes visible. Putting a `\pause` before the `\begin{itemize}` hides the images as well on the first slide. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 19):

Use the overlay specification `<+(1)->` instead of `<+->`, to offset the `+` in the overlay specification by 1:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Some text displayed on all slides in the frame.
    \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
    \item First item, uncovered on second slide
    \item Second item, uncovered on third slide. 
    \end{itemize}
Some more text to be displayed on all slides in the frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Animation:
[image]

Single frames: [First slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ewHo.png), [second slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEK7e.png), [third slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf61p.png)

Comment: Could you add complete code based on the OP's MWE?

Comment: @egreg: Good idea. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about _that_ additional syntax!

Comment: Nice animation, Qrrbrbirlbel! :)